# Is there a way to convert JSON String to direct object for Gantt Resource Chart in AnyChart?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2, anychart

So my current project involves me creating a gantt resource chart with the AnyChart API based on user input data for given tasks. I am using Jinja to allow for users to input the relevant information which is then rendered in the HTML template to output the chart.
In my .py file, I'm currently sending over this dictionary:

```
jsonData = {"id": "STUDY3ID", "name": "Study 03", "children": [{"id": "5", "name": "SDTM",  "periods": [{"id": "4_1", "start": "2018-01-12", "end": "2018-01-23", "resource": "Diana, Skylar"}],}]}
```

Because Gantt Resource Data requires keys that are not in quotation marks, I tried using a method to remove those quotation marks such as:

```
 var dataStr = '{{ jsonData | safe }}';
     = dataStr.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
```

However, to convert this correctly formatted string back into an object I can append to my tree data I was trying to use JSON.parse, which does not work since the string is no longer in appropriate JSON format. I was hoping there was another solution to figuring this out. I basically want to be able to create data child elements such as the "jsonData" variable above so they can be appended to my gantt resource chart. New to JS so apologies for any errors.

Comment: Doing anything like that with a regex, unless the data is **extremely** simple, will almost certainly end up being more work than writing your own serializer. Such a serializer would its own rules and could operate from a JavaScript object and generate a string (or whatever format you need) for the other representation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. In JSON, keys are always strings and strings are always quoted. Also, JSON is a text encoding meaning that in programming languages, it's always a string. The thing you're asigning to `jsonData` is a Python dict, not a JSON-formatted string. In Python, use [`JSON.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to convert the dict to a JSON-formatted string. In Javascript, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the JSON-formatted string to a Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data with marks quotation. But you missed wrapping your data in an array of objects. Your correct data will look like in [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/840JcRce/0).